# Integrate Google translation services in Outlook and Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, translation

I like the fact that MS Office 2010 and Outlook 2010 have translation options, but what I would prefer is to use Google's translation services which are a lot better than Microsoft Translation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this](http://translateclient.com/) is about as close as you are going to get to full integration

> Google Translate Client is a free translator for Windows which enables the fast translation of text in the most applications, such as Web Browsers, Office apps, Messengers and etc. using the Google Translate service.

Comment: The name of the application is misleading only the payed version support Google translate.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled across [this addin](http://outlook2010translate.codeplex.com/), and remembered this question. It should handle the functionality you need.